# Where is the workspace information for the Notes designer stored?

Tags: lotus-notes

Twice, the list of databases and all working sets have gotten emptied in my designer client. It has retained the working set names, but all the databases were no longer grouped in them or listed as choices to assign to working sets.

While this has had no adverse effects on the databases themselves, it has been annoying. I do switch between a personal ID and a signing ID, but the 'emptying' didn't coincide with that either time.

Has anyone else encountered this? Any ideas what might cause it? Is there an external file that holds these which is human-readable?

This is one of many things about 8.5.3 and Notes in general that's making me long for Notes 5 or 6.

Comment: I'm not flagging or downvoting, but I think this is pretty close to a 'chatty open-ended question', as described in the FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/faq  Perhaps at least changing the question title to something more specific would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never lost my working sets, but I keep thinking about backing up the definition, or editing it manually.

The working sets are defined in

> notes\data\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workingsets.xml

Here's [my source](http://blog.thimojansenit.nl/2011/05/bulk-cleanup-old-working-set-databases.html).

Phil

Comment: Oddly, the working sets shown in there aren't what I see in my Designer client, though it is time-stamped a minute ago.

Comment: Curious. Mine is correct.  The Working Sets are listed in the correct order, although the databases aren't listed in the order in which they are displayed.
Only other "interesting" thing I noticed is that the currently displayed working set (in my case "Live") is listed in the XML as 
<workingSet IMemento.internal.id="Live"/>
</workingSet>